# Is the "d" in "double x = 0.0d;" a g++ extension?

Tags: c++, g++

I have come across some code that basically is:

```
double x = 0.0d;
```

The `d` suggests to me that this is a suffix for doubles, but the [documentation for floating point literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) does not have it, and I cannot find any mention in the GNU g++ documentation. The compiler doesn't throw out any warnings either with `-Wall`.

---

I've made a [small sample on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nfNGSs) which answers my question with `-Wpedantic`, but I'd still like to see the documentation for this issue.

<sub>* Note that a [similar question for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41283474/1270789) exists.</sub>

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84717

Comment: @cpplearner Interesting - according to [this comment](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39027#c5) it may have been fixed in gcc 4.5.0, but it's still in my g++ 5.4.0

Comment: Searching for the word "suffix" (full word) in [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc.pdf) returned no relevant result.

Comment: Yes, it is a gcc extension (to both C and C++).    Historically some other programming languages use `E` and `D` interchangeably, and `E` is used for single precision (aka `float` in C++) output and `D` for double precision (aka `double` in C++) output.    Algol  (a language that was an ancestor of quite a few more modern languages, including C, Pascal, Fortran and others) also had a really funky floating point notation which used a subscripted "10" as an alternative to `E` or `D`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is specified in  ISO/IEC TR 24732 a.k.a. WG14 N1312 technical report "Extension for the programming language C to support decimal floating-point arithmetic".

It defines `d` as a suffix for plain `double` type, and several other suffixes for decimal floating point types.

[See it here (PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1312.pdf).

gcc documentation mentions all these other suffixes, but not `d`. It is an omission.